# Reset the whole view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a UITabBarController, each tabs governs it's own UITableViewController. I have a singleton User object in my app and I also have a logout button in which logs out the user and presents a modalViewController of the login page. When I logout I also have the User object to send a postNotification to the three UITableViewController in order to reset the view and stuff. The question is how do I reset the view so it's fresh like when someone starts with the app again, clearing previous data? What's the best way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When each tableview controller receives the notification, it can just empty the data array and reload the table.